# JS не видит POST-ответ с сервера

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, post, iis

У меня был проект на PHP (Yii) + JS (JQuery), крутился на сервере IIS 7, локально. Перенес проект на Windows Server 2008 c IIS 7, столкнулся с проблемой - ответ на мой POST-запрос приходит, но JS его "не видит". Вот код:

```
function timeChange() {
    $.post('/main/ajax_saveTimeChange/', {
        ...
    }, function(result) {
        console.log(result); // Никогда не срабатывает
        ...
    }, 'JSON');
}
```

Функция на стороне PHP:

```
public function actionAjax_saveTimeChange() {

    if (!Y::isAjaxRequest()) {
        throw new CHttpException(404);
    }

    ...

    print json_encode(array(
        'success' => !$intersection,
        'inputStart' => date("H:i", strtotime($input_start)),
        'inputEnd' => date("H:i", strtotime($input_end)),
        'totaly' => $this->calculateTotal($month_row, $mode),
        'info' => $d
    ));
}
```

Повторюсь. Локально, на моей машине - все работает. Приходит ответ, JS его обрабатывает. При работе проекта на другом сервере - не работает. Как будто ответа и вовсе не приходит.

При этом, если в хроме включить инструменты разработчика, перейти в Network, то можно увидеть, что ответ на запрос приходит. У ответа - валидное содержимое, то, которое я и хочу получить. Но JS его "не видит".

**UPD**

Заголовки:

```
POST /main/ajax_saveTimeChange/ HTTP/1.1
Host: tabgraf
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Cookie: PHPSESSID=133au0euq0eac1di1m51imkrq4
Origin: http://tabgraf
Referer: http://tabgraf/
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.71 Safari/537.36
X-DevTools-Emulate-Network-Conditions-Client-Id: 129B979C-479F-4B01-AFCA-CBE5C5D6A59C
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type,Content-Range,Content-Disposition,Content-Description
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Content-Length: 419
Content-Type: text/html
Date: Fri, 16 Oct 2015 06:19:33 GMT
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Pragma: no-cache
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.0
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.24
```

Так же заметил, если к `$.post(...)` добавить `.fail(function() {alert('Fail!!!');})` - то всегда выскакивает окошко "Fail!!!".

Comment: Какие-то ошибки есть? Какой код ответа приходит?

Comment: логи надо смотреть... может быть что угодно

Comment: Добавил доп. информацию в вопрос.

Comment: Функция fail() вызывается если, что-то пошло не так, например запрос вернул 404. Но у вас оно возвращает 200, в общем всё странно.

Comment: `.fail(function() {alert('Fail!!!');})` - ну так добавь ей аргумент и выведи ошибку.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я разобрался в чем была проблема. Не понятным для меня образом, файлы моего проекта которые имели кодировку UTF-8 "превратились" в UTF-8 with DOM. Из за этого, в ответах JSON c сервера присутствовал символ `\ufeff` и происходила ошибка.

Перекодировав все файлы в UTF-8 - ошибка исчезла.